# DataBind in C# - selectedvalue of ComboBox to Object property of a class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, selectedvalue

I'm facing some problem with databinding in C# windows Form project. I used .Net Framework 4 client profile. And IDE is visual studio 2010 express edition for C#. I have a class as below.

```
public myClass()
    {
        name = string.Empty;
        dataType = DataTypes.Bool;  //property with enum created by me
        isList = false;
        filterValue = new object();
    }
```

then I have a profile.csv file. In one of my form, I have a combobox and its datasource is datatable which include data from csv file.

```
private void form_load()
{
 ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
 this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
 comboBox.Name = attribute.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
 comboBox.DisplayMember = attribute.Name;
 comboBox.DataSource = attributeValueDataSource.Tables[tableName].DefaultView;
 comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Then I do data binding on this combo box to my class. As my data binding is in another method different from above and combo box is created dynamically, I found my combo box by it's name in below method.

```
private void Method_1
{
control = this.Controls.Find(attrName, true); 
ComboBox specificControl = (ComboBox)control[0]; Binding attributeBinding = 
new Binding(SelectedValue, attributeSelectionController.FilterAttributeModels[attributeCount] , FilterValue, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, string.Empty, F); 
attributeBinding.ControlUpdateMode =   ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;   specificControl.DataBindings.Add(attributeBinding);
 }
```

It seems fine till that state. But when binding event invoke and program flow go to the set property method, the value.GetType() return system.data.datarowview as type of selectedValue of combobox item instead of string or integer or any other datatype. I have tried to set value member for combox while I set datasource to its. But no help. Any one can help on it? I need urgent solution.

Comment: Can figured out. It's because of the order.

Answer (score 1):

Finally can figured out the problem. In form load method, I changed order of below lines.

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = attribute.Name; 
comboBox.DataSource = attributeValueDataSource.Tables[tableName].DefaultView;
```

as

```
comboBox.DataSource = attributeValueDataSource.Tables[tableName].DefaultView;
comboBox.DisplayMember = attribute.Name;
combox.ValueMember = attribute.Name;
```

Then it works.  :)

**credit to my friend who help me.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. You should be able to do it after 48 hours.